# Web app to collect images from other people

Tags: gratis, web-apps, images, sharing

I am collecting images from a recent event from a few different people.

I can use email, but the emails will probably be too big. I could use cloud storage, but that means everyone must have an account for that provider.

So, I am looking for a free web-app to allow other people to share pictures with me.

Requirements:

- free
- doesn't allow other people to view pictures other people have uploaded
- gives me a link I can share with the people
- doesn't require the other people to register/give any information - but it could ask for a password
- be as easy to use as possible

A quick Google shows me a lot of websites, but I can't seem to find any that match all the above requirements - do you know any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Balloon.io](https://balloon.io/)

> Balloon is a drop box for your Dropbox. Share your Balloon to receive files, collect photos from an event, and so much more straight to your Dropbox. There's no signup for senders, and no need for you to manually download files anymore.

It's very simple to use - just login with your Dropbox account and make a *balloon* - you can optionally make a password.

You will then get a link to share with people where they can upload directly to your Dropbox account.

- free
- easy to use
- only you can view the uploaded pictures
- uploaders don't need to give any details
- gives you a shareable link

Answer (score 2):

Try [DBinbox](https://dbinbox.com/). DBinbox has a basic free plan, allows users to upload data to your Dropbox without registration, and seems to meet your other requirements as well. The only downside is that the service has two limitations on its free plan: max 20 MB per file and max 300 MB total uploaded per month.

Also, for reference, check out [Jotform](http://www.jotform.com/dropbox/) for Dropbox. If you setup a very basic webpage, you can embed a script which allows people to upload files directly to your Dropbox. You could also do this by making your own basic web page and allowing users to upload data to the host server, but it sounds like you want a dedicated option.

Comment: 300mb is pretty small! But +1, I can use these options in the future if needed. I'll wait for any other answers for now...

Comment: I've found Balloon - see my answer! :)